# How to run @headlessui/vue in Nuxt 3 project?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, headless-ui

I'm trying to run `@headlessui/vue` package in Nuxt3 project.

I'm able to see the package in `node_modules` folder.

But I keep getting below error

`Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "@headlessui/vue" from "components/LeftSideFilter.vue". Does the file exist?`

LeftSideFilter.vue file code

````
        <!--
    This example requires Tailwind CSS v2.0+ 
    
    This example requires some changes to your config:
    
    ```
    // tailwind.config.js
    module.exports = {
        // ...
        plugins: [
        // ...
        require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
        ],
    }
    ```
    -->
    <template>
    <div class="bg-white">
        <div>
        <!-- Mobile filter dialog -->
        <TransitionRoot as="template" :show="mobileFiltersOpen">
            <Dialog
            as="div"
            class="fixed inset-0 flex z-40 lg:hidden"
            @close="mobileFiltersOpen = false"
            >
            <TransitionChild
                as="template"
                enter="transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300"
                enter-from="opacity-0"
                enter-to="opacity-100"
                leave="transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300"
                leave-from="opacity-100"
                leave-to="opacity-0"
            >
                <DialogOverlay class="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-25" />
            </TransitionChild>

            <TransitionChild
                as="template"
                enter="transition ease-in-out duration-300 transform"
                enter-from="translate-x-full"
                enter-to="translate-x-0"
                leave="transition ease-in-out duration-300 transform"
                leave-from="translate-x-0"
                leave-to="translate-x-full"
            >
                <div
                class="ml-auto relative max-w-xs w-full h-full bg-white shadow-xl py-4 pb-12 flex flex-col overflow-y-auto"
                >
                <div class="px-4 flex items-center justify-between">
                    <h2 class="text-lg font-medium text-gray-900">Filters</h2>
                    <button
                    type="button"
                    class="-mr-2 w-10 h-10 bg-white p-2 rounded-md flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400"
                    @click="mobileFiltersOpen = false"
                    >
                    <span class="sr-only">Close menu</span>
                    <XIcon class="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Filters -->
                <form class="mt-4 border-t border-gray-200">
                    <h3 class="sr-only">Categories</h3>
                    <ul role="list" class="font-medium text-gray-900 px-2 py-3">
                    <li v-for="category in subCategories" :key="category.name">
                        <a :href="category.href" class="block px-2 py-3">
                        {{ category.name }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>

                    <Disclosure
                    as="div"
                    v-for="section in filters"
                    :key="section.id"
                    class="border-t border-gray-200 px-4 py-6"
                    v-slot="{ open }"
                    >
                    <h3 class="-mx-2 -my-3 flow-root">
                        <DisclosureButton
                        class="px-2 py-3 bg-white w-full flex items-center justify-between text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500"
                        >
                        <span class="font-medium text-gray-900">
                            {{ section.name }}
                        </span>
                        <span class="ml-6 flex items-center">
                            <PlusSmIcon
                            v-if="!open"
                            class="h-5 w-5"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                            />
                            <MinusSmIcon
                            v-else
                            class="h-5 w-5"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                            />
                        </span>
                        </DisclosureButton>
                    </h3>
                    <DisclosurePanel class="pt-6">
                        <div class="space-y-6">
                        <div
                            v-for="(option, optionIdx) in section.options"
                            :key="option.value"
                            class="flex items-center"
                        >
                            <input
                            :id="`filter-mobile-${section.id}-${optionIdx}`"
                            :name="`${section.id}[]`"
                            :value="option.value"
                            type="checkbox"
                            :checked="option.checked"
                            class="h-4 w-4 border-gray-300 rounded text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                            />
                            <label
                            :for="`filter-mobile-${section.id}-${optionIdx}`"
                            class="ml-3 min-w-0 flex-1 text-gray-500"
                            >
                            {{ option.label }}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </DisclosurePanel>
                    </Disclosure>
                </form>
                </div>
            </TransitionChild>
            </Dialog>
        </TransitionRoot>

        <main class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div
            class="relative z-10 flex items-baseline justify-between pt-24 pb-6 border-b border-gray-200"
            >
            <h1 class="text-4xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-900">
                New Arrivals
            </h1>

            <div class="flex items-center">
                <Menu as="div" class="relative inline-block text-left">
                <div>
                    <MenuButton
                    class="group inline-flex justify-center text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900"
                    >
                    Sort
                    <ChevronDownIcon
                        class="flex-shrink-0 -mr-1 ml-1 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                    />
                    </MenuButton>
                </div>

                <transition
                    enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-100"
                    enter-from-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                    enter-to-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-75"
                    leave-from-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    leave-to-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                >
                    <MenuItems
                    class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-40 rounded-md shadow-2xl bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none"
                    >
                    <div class="py-1">
                        <MenuItem
                        v-for="option in sortOptions"
                        :key="option.name"
                        v-slot="{ active }"
                        >
                        <a
                            :href="option.href"
                            :class="[
                            option.current
                                ? 'font-medium text-gray-900'
                                : 'text-gray-500',
                            active ? 'bg-gray-100' : '',
                            'block px-4 py-2 text-sm',
                            ]"
                        >
                            {{ option.name }}
                        </a>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </div>
                    </MenuItems>
                </transition>
                </Menu>

                <button
                type="button"
                class="p-2 -m-2 ml-5 sm:ml-7 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500"
                >
                <span class="sr-only">View grid</span>
                <ViewGridIcon class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                </button>
                <button
                type="button"
                class="p-2 -m-2 ml-4 sm:ml-6 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 lg:hidden"
                @click="mobileFiltersOpen = true"
                >
                <span class="sr-only">Filters</span>
                <FilterIcon class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                </button>
            </div>
            </div>

            <section aria-labelledby="products-heading" class="pt-6 pb-24">
            <h2 id="products-heading" class="sr-only">Products</h2>

            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-x-8 gap-y-10">
                <!-- Filters -->
                <form class="hidden lg:block">
                <h3 class="sr-only">Categories</h3>
                <ul
                    role="list"
                    class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 space-y-4 pb-6 border-b border-gray-200"
                >
                    <li v-for="category in subCategories" :key="category.name">
                    <a :href="category.href">
                        {{ category.name }}
                    </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <Disclosure
                    as="div"
                    v-for="section in filters"
                    :key="section.id"
                    class="border-b border-gray-200 py-6"
                    v-slot="{ open }"
                >
                    <h3 class="-my-3 flow-root">
                    <DisclosureButton
                        class="py-3 bg-white w-full flex items-center justify-between text-sm text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500"
                    >
                        <span class="font-medium text-gray-900">
                        {{ section.name }}
                        </span>
                        <span class="ml-6 flex items-center">
                        <PlusSmIcon
                            v-if="!open"
                            class="h-5 w-5"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                        />
                        <MinusSmIcon v-else class="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </span>
                    </DisclosureButton>
                    </h3>
                    <DisclosurePanel class="pt-6">
                    <div class="space-y-4">
                        <div
                        v-for="(option, optionIdx) in section.options"
                        :key="option.value"
                        class="flex items-center"
                        >
                        <input
                            :id="`filter-${section.id}-${optionIdx}`"
                            :name="`${section.id}[]`"
                            :value="option.value"
                            type="checkbox"
                            :checked="option.checked"
                            class="h-4 w-4 border-gray-300 rounded text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                        />
                        <label
                            :for="`filter-${section.id}-${optionIdx}`"
                            class="ml-3 text-sm text-gray-600"
                        >
                            {{ option.label }}
                        </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </DisclosurePanel>
                </Disclosure>
                </form>

                <!-- Product grid -->
                <div class="lg:col-span-3">
                <RightSide />
                <RightSide /> <RightSide /> <RightSide />
                </div>
            </div>
            </section>
        </main>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import RightSide from "./RightSide.vue";
    import { ref } from "vue";
    import {
    Dialog,
    DialogOverlay,
    Disclosure,
    DisclosureButton,
    DisclosurePanel,
    Menu,
    MenuButton,
    MenuItem,
    MenuItems,
    TransitionChild,
    TransitionRoot,
    } from "@headlessui/vue";
    import { XIcon } from "@heroicons/vue/outline";
    import {
    ChevronDownIcon,
    FilterIcon,
    MinusSmIcon,
    PlusSmIcon,
    ViewGridIcon,
    } from "@heroicons/vue/solid";

    const sortOptions = [
    { name: "Most Popular", href: "#", current: true },
    { name: "Best Rating", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "Newest", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "Price: Low to High", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "Price: High to Low", href: "#", current: false },
    ];
    const subCategories = [
    { name: "Totes", href: "#" },
    { name: "Backpacks", href: "#" },
    { name: "Travel Bags", href: "#" },
    { name: "Hip Bags", href: "#" },
    { name: "Laptop Sleeves", href: "#" },
    ];
    const filters = [
    {
        id: "color",
        name: "Color",
        options: [
        { value: "white", label: "White", checked: false },
        { value: "beige", label: "Beige", checked: false },
        { value: "blue", label: "Blue", checked: true },
        { value: "brown", label: "Brown", checked: false },
        { value: "green", label: "Green", checked: false },
        { value: "purple", label: "Purple", checked: false },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "category",
        name: "Category",
        options: [
        { value: "new-arrivals", label: "New Arrivals", checked: false },
        { value: "sale", label: "Sale", checked: false },
        { value: "travel", label: "Travel", checked: true },
        { value: "organization", label: "Organization", checked: false },
        { value: "accessories", label: "Accessories", checked: false },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "size",
        name: "Size",
        options: [
        { value: "2l", label: "2L", checked: false },
        { value: "6l", label: "6L", checked: false },
        { value: "12l", label: "12L", checked: false },
        { value: "18l", label: "18L", checked: false },
        { value: "20l", label: "20L", checked: false },
        { value: "40l", label: "40L", checked: true },
        ],
    },
    ];

    export default {
    components: {
        Dialog,
        DialogOverlay,
        Disclosure,
        DisclosureButton,
        DisclosurePanel,
        Menu,
        MenuButton,
        MenuItem,
        MenuItems,
        TransitionChild,
        TransitionRoot,
        ChevronDownIcon,
        FilterIcon,
        MinusSmIcon,
        PlusSmIcon,
        ViewGridIcon,
        XIcon,
        RightSide,
    },
    setup() {
        const mobileFiltersOpen = ref(false);

        return {
        sortOptions,
        subCategories,
        filters,
        mobileFiltersOpen,
        };
    },
    };
    </script>
````

Comment: Hi, could you please highlight, format and narrow down your code snippet to only the relevant part? There is a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the module that comes with Nuxt 3.

Follow these steps
https://nuxt.com/modules/headlessui